# Is there a way to set the default folder row and column font size in Outlook 365?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

By default, all folders default to 8pt type in Outlook, which was fine in, oh, 1990. Is there some hack anyone knows of to set it to default to, for my preference, 10pt type?[image]

Comment: Outlook uses your display's DPI setting to scale up on larger screens. Microsoft expects that users set the DPI to a higher value if all text is too small. So it is better to increase the DPI in windows to fix this issue, than to go by every program that you use and try to do it there.

Comment: Are you looking to [Change the default font or text color for email messages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-default-font-or-text-color-for-email-messages-1aabb236-01d4-4faf-b998-a4087da3ceab)?

Comment: @LPChip  This isn't about DPI, it's about the fact that Outlook defaults to 8pt text (as per image included in my question, and looking for a way change the default.  As in is there a registry hack or some setting that's non-obvious.

Comment: @harrymc  I stated in the question that it's about folders, not message text. When you create a new folder they default to 8pt text.

Comment: It is listed as 8pt, but it is larger if the DPI scales it up. As far as I know, there is no way to change it other than changing the DPI system-wide.

Comment: Have you tried *View > Change View >  Manage views*, modify the current view, then used *View > Change View > Apply Current View to other Mail folders*?

Comment: @LPChip Do you actually have many PCs with different monitors, different resolutions, different DPI settings?  Looks like you don't because it has zero effect,  it's 8pt or nothing, and it's ALWAYS too small.

Comment: I do have it, and on my system it actually does have effect. But I do have to change the DPI setting and then close/reopen outlook before outlook understands. Keep in mind, that outlook still says it is 8pt, but the text definitely gets bigger.

Comment: @harrymc This is the closest to a good answer and it does work...to a limited extent.

It will do so for existing folders but does NOT address the question that when you create a new one, it's stuck in the 90's when 8pt stuff was fine.  And ignore LPCHip on this, he has no clue, DPI has zero to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

The poster remarked that my following suggestion
does work ... to a limited extent:

- Use *View > Change View > Manage views*
- Modify the current view
- Use *View > Change View > Apply Current View to other Mail folders*
- New folders will now use these settings.

Comment: What do you mean by "limited extent"?

Comment: Means that you still need to do this whenever you create a new folder which was not the object of my question.  To be clear, the question was to change the default font for all new Outlook folders from 8pt type which is useless, irrespective of what LPChip keeps going on about which assumes I am clueless about DPI.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want set it as shown in the figure below?

[image]

If so, agree with harrymc, we can change it via View Settings. And I notice that you are worried that this view cannot be applied to the new folder, so it's suggested that you could create a new view test1 and set the required size of the column and row format. When you create a new folder, simply apply test1 to the new folder by clicking the folder and selecting test1.

[image]

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back.